# Properties of Bessel Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, bessel-functions

I have shown that the Bessel function
$$J_n\left(x\right)=\dfrac{x^n}{2^n}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\dfrac{\left(-1\right)^kx^{2k}}{2^{2k}k!\left(n+k\right)!}$$
satisfies the property

$$\left(x^{n+1}J_{n+1}\left(x\right)\right)'=x^{n+1}J_{n}\left(x\right)$$

Hence or otherwise, show that 
$$J'_{n+1}\left(x\right)=J_n\left(x\right)-\dfrac{n+1}{x}J_{n+1}\left(x\right)$$

Comment: .. what do you get for $J_n\left(x\right)-\dfrac{n+1}{x}J_{n+1}\left(x\right)$ as a power series ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the basic properties of Bessel functions is 
$(x^{n+1}J_{n+1}(x))'=x^{n+1}J_{n}(x)$ (It should be $J_{n}(x)$ on the R.H.S of your equation).
It can be easily derived by substituting $n+1$ in place of $n$ in the power series expression of $J_{n}(x)$ and differentiating w.r.t $x$.
Then by expanding the L.H.S in the above equation using chain rule and rearranging, the required equation/identity can be obtained.